# How to add URL as parameter in msiexec?

Tags: command-line, url, parameters

I'm trying to install a program using msiexec from 'CMD' and I'm trying to add a URL parameter.

So it looks like this:

```
Msiexec /i \\spfil001\MSI\esdh\offext.msi URL=http://stesdh01
```

But I must be doing something wrong cause when the installation starts it says

> "You must set the URL parameter or the program will not complete".

I'm guessing my syntax is wrong. Could someone help me? I tried everything I could think off
with `""` and `''`, `()`.

Answer (score 2):

And the problem was.. I didn't run CMD as administrator.. even though I was administrator it required I right clicked on it and hit "run as administrator" .. so now it works.

Comment: Just because you're an administrator doesn't mean that everything you run automatically executes with full permissions. For more information, read up about [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). Also, remember to accept your answer so other people who find your question will know what helped you.